# Javascript - How to make array.includes work with a list of dictionnaries?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, include

Let's say I have an array containing multiple dictionaries like so :

```
var coords = [{'x': 0, 'y': 0}, {'x': 2, 'y': 5}, {'x': 1, 'y': 6}]
```

And I try to run a `array.includes` on it, it simply doesn't work :

```
console.log( coords.includes({'x': 0, 'y': 0}) )
// Output : false
```

It only does this when I work with an array containing dictionaries. For example this works just fine :

```
var coords = ['0-0', '2-5', '1-6']
console.log( coords.includes('0-0') )
// Output : true
```

Is there a reason for this? And would there be a way to make it work with dictionaries?

Comment: in javascript `{'x': 0, 'y': 0} != {'x': 0, 'y': 0}` so, you'll need to do `coords.find` instead

Comment: so, you'll need to do `coords.some()` instead

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to search for dictionaries in an array.

We can first use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) on the array and convert all of the elements to JSON strings.

```js
const coords = [{'x': 0, 'y': 0}, {'x': 2, 'y': 5}, {'x': 1, 'y': 6}]
.map(elm => JSON.stringify(elm));
```

After doing that, searching is pretty straightforward.

```js
const target = {'x': 0, 'y': 0}; // object you're searching for
console.log(coords.includes(JSON.stringify(target))); // true
```

This works because you're are now comparing strings (output from `JSON.string()`) instead of comparing objects (which is just comparing object references instead of the contents).